# Unable to install KB3012973 Windows Update through scripts

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, restart, windows-update

I've been trying to update my server (Windows 10 Pro / 1903 Version) to version 2004 (KB3012973) through various Powershell scripts, but they all seem to apply no changes, at all, after restarting the machine.

 Quite important to mention, I was successfully able to install previous updates through these scripts without any errors.

So, let me walk you through the process (PSWindowsUpdate):

1. First, looking for updates and using 'Install-WindowsUpdate' to install them all:[image: Installation process as can be seen in the image.]
2. Rebooting the machine through either the script or manually by pressing on the 'Restart' button in the Start menu.
3. Letting the machine restart.... Then going into the Windows Update menu:[image: Windows Update menu after restart]
   And viola! After restart, the windows version is just the same as it was before.

I have also tried running the script from the '[Searching, Downloading, and Installing Updates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wua_sdk/searching--downloading--and-installing-updates)' tutorial by Microsoft, with no luck, as it seems.
I'd also like to note that oddly the update can be installed manually, by pressing the 'Install Now' button, which is sadly not what I'm looking for. As mentioned, the scripts have worked smoothly for previous updates.
Any help would be truly greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you checked with your admins? that "some settings are managed by your organization" msg may be part of your problem.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Hey Lee, here is a screenshot of our organization's policy: https://i.imgur.com/bXSYkm5.png
Do you think that might have anything to do with the update failure? I didn't look at it too long since previous updates worked just fine through scripts.

Comment: Also, I think my question is similar to this question: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/9d42900e-5e26-4711-aa6b-16e9a7cfd1f8/how-to-call-from-powershell-update-and-restart?forum=win10itprosetup . Though they don't explain much how they managed to solve their problem, which isn't too much of a help. However, it seems to even be the same update version.

Comment: [1] pics of text are disrecommended. [*grin*] one is normally supposed to simply insert the text into the Question - perhaps wrapping it in code formatting markers. [2] i don't see anything that seems related to your problem ... but you still otta speak with your admins to find out if they have some _other_ blocking method activated.

Comment: I smell more of a WU component reset required, as I've seen these symptoms in few of my organisation's systems in the past. Please try resetting the WU component using the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/windows-update-resources, and then try re-download, and re-install. Check if this helps you!

Comment: As far as i know simple restart won't make this feature update affective. If you are doing installation via windows update api. You need to call Commit after you install feature update. Then you can restart.